# Error installing RODBC package

Tags: linux, centos6, cloudera-quickstart-vm

Iam trying to install RODBC on my Cloudera server but Iam getting an error when downloading the package... is there anyone that can tell me what Iam doing wrong?

Below my logs:
http://pastebin.com/s2b1y0Xr

Comment: Try using "sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev" and then the install within R should work

Comment: I already installed the unixodbc-dev package

Answer (score 1):

---

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl .. ... : ld returned 1 exit status

`-lcurl` means `libcurl.so` : Provided by libcurl4-gnutls-dev, libcurl4-nss-dev, libcurl4-openssl-dev
https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&arch=amd64&searchon=contents&keywords=libcurl.so

If e.g. CentOS, RHEL : libcurl-devel

---

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, i installed the libcurl package (without -dev) so i will try the libcurl-dev instead... or is there no difference between those two packages...?

Comment: `libcurl-dev` is not "instead" . `curl` is `libcurl*-***` with the run time files. And `libcurl-devel` contains the development files : Needed for building applications with curl. -

Answer (score 0):

Solved by installing the package via yum

`sudo yum install R-RODBC`